# Is it possible to specify ESLint input files in the .exlintrc.js file?

Tags: eslint

I want to check my JS project by simply running `npx eslint` and specify input file globs in the `.eslintrc.js` config file, alongside with check rules. Unfortunately, I can't find anything resembling "input files" in the official documentation or Google, all examples assumes that files/globs are passed to the ESLint binary as command-line args. Is it any way to specify input files in the config file instead?